# How to marshal a predicate from JSON in Prolog?

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

In Python it is common to [marshal objects from JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html). I am seeking similar functionality in Prolog, either `swi-prolog` or `scryer`.

For instance, if we have JSON stating

```
{'predicate': 
  {'mortal(X)', ':-', 'human(X)'}
}
```

I'm hoping to find something like load_predicates(j) and have that data immediately consulted.  A version of `json.dumps()` and `loads()` would also be extremely useful.

EDIT: For clarity, this will allow interoperability with client applications which will be collecting rules from users.  That application is probably not in Prolog, but something like React.js.

Comment: How could Prolog "benefit" from such JSON wrapping, when it can already parse Prolog code? See e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1

Comment: IMO this is really three questions. 1. Converting Prolog clauses to/from JSON. 2. Validating JSON is proper representation of Prolog clauses. 3. Consulting a file.

Comment: What I really don't get is why store Prolog clauses as JSON? For me this only makes sense if you have thousands of Prolog clauses created and validated as such for use with another application. Other than that I would write a one-off to convert them to a *.pl file.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the commenters that it would be easier to convert the JSON data to a `.pl` file in the proper format first and then load that.

However, you can load the predicates from JSON directly, convert them to a representation that Prolog understands, and use `assertz` to add them to the knowledge base.

If indeed the data contains all the syntax needed for a predicate (as is the case in the example data in the question) then converting the representation is fairly simple as you just need to concatenate the elements of the list into a string and then create a term out of the string. Note that this assumption skips step 2 in the first [comment by Guy Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971452/how-to-marshal-a-predicate-from-json-in-prolog#comment132307485_74971452).

Note that the Prolog JSON library is rather strict in which format it accepts: only double quotes are valid as string delimiters, and lists with singleton values (i.e., not key-value pairs) need to use the notation `[a,b,c]` instead of `{a,b,c}`. So first the example data needs to be rewritten:

```json
{"predicate": 
  ["mortal(X)", ":-", "human(X)"]
}
```

Then you can load it in SWI-Prolog. Minimal working example:

```
:- use_module(library(http/json)).

% example fact for testing
human(aristotle).

load_predicate(J) :-
   % open the file
   open(J, read, JSONstream, []),
   % parse the JSON data
   json_read(JSONstream, json(L)),
   % check for an occurrence of the predicate key with value L2
   member(predicate=L2, L),
   % concatenate the list into a string
   atomics_to_string(L2, S),
   % create a term from the string
   term_string(T, S),
   % add to knowledge base
   assertz(T).
```

Example run:

```
?- consult('mwe.pl').
true.
?- load_predicate('example_predicate.json').
true.
?- mortal(X).
X = aristotle.
```

Detailed explanation:

The predicate `json_read` stores the data in the following form:

```
json([predicate=['mortal(X)', :-, 'human(X)']])
```

This is a list inside a `json` term with one element for each key-value pair. The element has the syntax `key=value`. In the call to `json_read` you can already strip the `json()` term and store the list directly in the variable `L`.

Then `member/2` is used to search for the compound term `predicate=L2`. If you have more than one predicate in the JSON file then you should turn this into a foreach or in a recursive call to process all predicates in the list.

Since the list `L2` already contains a syntactically well-formed Prolog predicate it can just be concatenated, turned into a term using `term_string/2` and asserted. Note that in case the predicate is not yet in the required format, you can construct a predicate out of the various pieces using built-in predicate manipulation functionality, see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=copy_predicate_clauses/2 for some pointers.